# Git (on Windows using msysgit) - "compound" command

Tags: git, bash, git-alias

I need to do several "two-step" or "three-step" commands in Git quite frequently, that require me to also specify a branch name as a parameter - things like:

```
git checkout (branch name)
git pull origin (branch name)
```

or stuff like that. I would like to "automate" this into an alias - but a simple Git alias won't do - right?

So how can I do this in a Bash shell script? I am well versed in MS-DOS/Windows batch scripts - but I am a total newbie to Bash.

All the examples of Bash alias with more than one Git command I've seen so far seem to *not* have any parameters...... but I am jumping back and forth between various branches, so I definitely need to define **which** branch to check out and update from the central repo...

Any help? Any blog posts or articles that a *nix newbie would understand? Any pointers are highly welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an alias like this:

```
[alias]
  chepull = !git checkout $1 && git pull origin
```

You can do:

```
git chepull branch_name
```

Note: `$1` is intentionally not specified in `git pull origin`, but should work as intended.

Comment: Hm.... so if I checkout `SomeExperimentalBranch` - don't I have to define that branch in the `git pull origin`, too, for it to be updated from the central repo ??

Comment: @marc_s - What I mean is, the above alias will do `git pull origin SomeExperimentalBranch`